# How to create color map / heatmap from color contours?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, heatmap, contour

I have an Image like the below:

[image: a CT image that I extracted contours of tumor from it]

and I want to make this image to heatmap by its contours.
[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5UQf.png)

Is there any solution in OpenCV or others for that?

(in fact, this Image is a slice of CT image that I extract contours of tumor and organ at risk from that and the raw image is like below:
[raw image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIqtr.png))

Thanks

based on solutions that others guided me and thanks a lot for their solutions, a sample for output now is something like that: [heatmap based on distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3RQj.jpg) but now another problem appears that sometimes it doesn't have segmentation for colorful contours accurately :(

Comment: [Contour lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) never cross. I'm not sure what your picture would ever represent.

Comment: yes, you're right. in fact, these contours are for a CT slice. these contours encompass the tumor, the organs at risk in the image. I extract these contours from the CT image and my purpose is these contours will convert to the heatmap. but i don't know how to do that :(

Comment: what is your idea of a "heat map"? the term has a specific meaning and you haven't explained how it applies here. do you mean something else that isn't a heatmap?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz. excuse me. I have edited my question and added a sample image for my purpose.

Comment: Your contours are not conducive to heat map except as an overlay. A color heat map is mostly applied to slowly changing regions of intensity in bands, not lines. Perhaps your raw CT scan might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to generate a distance field, where for each pixel within the closed contour, calculate its distance to the contour (several methods possible, please do your research), then color mapping the distance to a color. I guess this is what do you mean by a "heat map".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do it but took a long time to implement and according to your solution I draw the dose map based on distance. but unfortunately I have problem to segment the contours

Comment: and now I've added a sample of output in my question, above.